# Using Bootstrap 3, how can I un-stack cols as the breakpoints get smaller?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I know there is a few ways to do this, but I want to put this out there to see if there are any clean / good examples of ways to do this as I haven't had any luck searching.

So in Bootstrap, I basically have an aside that goes full width under 780px.  Just thinking about that aside, it is a unique situation where that section actually gets larger as the viewport gets smaller.

Let me try to clarify...  say the entire page width is 1200px and I am using a container -> row -> col-md-9 & a col-md-3.  The col-md-3 is the aside.  Inside the col-md-3 is a form with a nested grid of 2x col-sm-6 divs.  So as the page drops through the break points, when it gets under 980px, the aside becomes full width and thus wider than it was at 1200px.

Bootstrap is setup so if you use col-sm-6 that column goes from 50% width to 100% width under 780px.  I need to figure out how to do the opposite of that.

I need col-sm-6 (or however I need to custom tag, etc.) to go from 100% length to 50% length under 780px.

How can I do this?  Thanks in advance!

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-sm-6">Box 1</div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6">Box 2</div>
    
  </div>
  
<div>
```

So in the example above...  Box 1 and Box 2 stay next to each other until the viewport width is below 768px.

What would be the best way to write this so Box 1 and Box 2 were stacked until the viewport went below 768px wide... then they go on the same line / inline / whatever?

Comment: Consider posting a code sample, it will easier for everyone to understand your scenario and help you on what you ask.

Comment: When you say length are you referring to the width?

Comment: Added code and, thank you, yes I meant width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple `col-*-*` classes on any columns within a bootstrap `row`. In your case, you would use `col-xs-6 col-sm-12` to make any columns appear side-by-side on the smallest layout, but stacked on anything above:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
      Box 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
      Box 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/oRtYXhDPTr) demonstrating this behaviour.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot for now figuring that out.  I knew there was a simple answer.  Thank you!  :)

Comment: No problem! Just a heads up, stuff might get a bit squished if you try to inline columns at lower sizes, so just be aware of that.

Comment: Thanks for that Tim...   it's actually a weird situation where the side bar becomes full size and has this nested row so as the viewport gets smaller, that container gets put in stack and actually becomes bigger.  Hard to explain well without seeing it.  ...but this solution is perfect!  Thanks so much!  =)

Comment: Haha I see. Sounds interesting :P If you found this solution helpful, feel free to upvote and/or select it as an accepted answer so others with the same problem can benefit from it. Cheers!